# traverse among the columns of oracle tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle11g

This trigger propose to track the old and new values on customer table.
It only inserts a new row for every changed value columns.
Imagine there are twentyfive columns and I got to write the same thing for 25 times.
Are there any way to do this in a loop or any better way to keep more generic. Imagine If any new columnd added to customer table, with the way you tell me there will be no need to alter the trigger.

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER KRD_CUSTOMER_UPD_DEL_TRG 
       BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE ON KRD_CUSTOMER 
       FOR EACH ROW 
    DECLARE 
       V_ISLEMTIPI VARCHAR2(1); 
    BEGIN 
       IF UPDATING THEN 
           if      :OLD.CUSTOMERNAME <> :NEW.CUSTOMERNAME then
        krd_ins_customerTable(p_OldCustomerName => :OLD.CUSTOMERNAME,
                                    p_NewCustomerName => :NEW.CUSTOMERNAME);
       end if;
       end if;

    end;
```

Comment: FWIW, you might want to handle NULL values of `CUSTOMERNAME` in your trigger explicitly.

Comment: The most workable approach is to dynamically create a static trigger. (That is use SQL to generate the trigger.)  blgnkc provided a link to Tom Kyte's solution, as a comment to the answer from Rene.   http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:59412348055

Answer (score 0):

The column names are available in the view: user_tab_columns.

Something that may work:
Loop through the column names in this view and construct a string containing the statement that must be executed for that particular column.

```
l_statement := 'begin if :OLD.<columname> <> :NEW.<columname> then
        krd_ins_customerTable(p_Old<columname> => :OLD.<columname>,
                                    p_New<columname> => :NEW.<columname>); end;'

execute immediate l_statement;
```

As Ollie already commented: To check for non equality also check the null values.

```
If (a is null and b is not null)
or (a is not null and b is null)
or (a is not null and b is not null and a!=b)
```

Comment: @ http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:59412348055 it says impossible :(

Comment: Even if you could get this to work, for performance reasons, you would really want to avoid that recursive call to USER_TAB_COLUMNS and the overhead of the EXECUTE IMMEDIATEs. That's just a lot of heavy lifting for the database to do FOR EACH ROW changed. I second the comment from blgnklc. Use Tom Kyte's approach.